# Terracotta L2 cache invalidation by messaging

Tags: caching, terracotta, invalidation

I am trying to evaluate Terracotta Disctributed Cache with ehcache. I have the following query. There are 20+ apps which will use a TAS distributed cache. As I understand there will be a L1 cache in each of these apps and a L2 in the cluster. The cluster cache data is fronting a Database which will be updated by a different app which we do not have access to. So we only read from this DB. But the DB updates needs to flow to the cache.

By the way of DB triggers the updated (keys alone) are stored in a temp table. In specific intervals a job monitors this table and collects the keys in the cache that needs to be expired. This is a separate batch job.

From here I need help. How do I inform the TAS L2 cache to expire/evict these keys? What options in terracotta are there?. Will this expiry event flow from L2 to all the individual apps? What is the time lag? I do not want to send the expiry keys to all the individual apps. Can this be accomplished?.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something, but I am not sure why you would want to expire/evict those keys instead of simply calling cache.removeAll(keys). This removal will be automatically propagated to all L1 nodes which have those entries in their local cache.

The time lag depends on the consistency settings of the distributed cache.